# How wide-spread is this GNU extension on ternary operation?

Tags: c++, c, ternary-operator

This is a GNU extension on ternary operation according to the [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:#C).

```
iMyVal = --iVal ?: iDft;
```

While I'm fully aware that this is a GNU extension, but sometimes things may come in very handy with this special syntax.

So, does anybody know if this syntax is only available in `gcc`?  Or are they any other compilers which support it?

*to anyone who's interested, PHP started supporting this syntax from 5.3*

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why use that extension when you can simply use `iMyVal = --iVal ? --iVal : iDft;` I don't know if its *only* available in GCC, but I can definitely tell you that it is *not* available in MSVC. In any case, if you want your code to be compatible, just don't use compiler specific extensions... If you have to ask like you're doing now, don't use it.

Comment: @vanneto, your suggestion is buggy - it decrements `iVal` twice. You could fix it, but it gets tricky if wrapped in a macro.

Comment: Why do you want to take the risk of being non-portable by omitting one single token? IMHO, `iMyVal = --iVal ? iVal : iDft;` is not significantly more typing effort, but more readable, more understandable and portable.

Comment: Yeah, sorry, just wanted to fix my code. In any case, if you want to be portable, you will just have to avoid such syntactic sugar (IMO more like salt in this case).

Comment: @Andreas The example provided is oversimplified.  Let's see... try to think of `strtok_r`.  ;)

Comment: This extension has become less useful now that C++11 has `auto`. You can rewrite the example as `auto tmp = --iVal; iMyVal = tmp ? tmp : iDft`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Some answers:

1. GCC - yes
2. MSVC - no (based on vanetto's answer)
3. CLANG - <strike>no</strike> yes - [the LLVM online compiler](http://llvm.org/demo/index.cgi) compiles it successfully.
4. Intel C compiler - yes

Bottom line - <strike>not wide-spread. Only Intel's compiler, which is almost 100% gcc-compatible, supports this.</strike>?

Comment: I would expect CLANG to support it, since they use CLANG to compile Linux Kernel which uses a lot of gcc extensions.

Comment: Thanks @MaximYegorushkin, seems like it does support it.

Comment: @ugoren Thank you.  This fact sheet is what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1):

C++11 workaround:

```
template<typename Fcond, typename Flast>
auto ternary2support(Fcond fcond, Flast flast) -> decltype(fcond())
{
  auto    cond_result= fcond();
  return  cond_result? cond_result : flast();
}


#define ternary2(c,case0) ternary2support(  [&](){ return (c);}, [&](){ return (case0);} )


void test_tern2()
{
  int i= 3;

  int res1= ternary2(--i,1000);
  int res2= ternary2(--i,1000);
  int res3= ternary2(--i,1000);

  std::cout<<" res1="<< res1<<" res2="<< res2<<" res3="<< res3;
  // output: res1=2 res2=1 res3=1000

}

int main(){test_tern2(); return 0;}
```

Lambda lasyness prevents the condition recalculation and unnecassary case0 expression evaluation (as the original ternary operator extension works)