# Ternary operator with nothing in 'if' condition

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ternary-operator

What does the following code do?

```
return obj ? : [NSNull null];
```

From my understanding of ternary operations it would be equivalent to:

```
if (!obj)
    return [NSNull null];
```

But what gets returned `if (obj)`? Does it fall through to still `return [NSNull null]`?

Comment: It's a non-standard GNU extension - see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12420144/how-wide-spread-is-this-gnu-extension-on-ternary-operation

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The code...

```
return foo ? : bar;
```

Will return the same value as...

```
return foo ? foo : bar;
```

The difference is that the first method only inspects the `foo` value once.

It is better to use the first in several cases.

For instance, creating an object...

```
// this would create two objects, one to check and the other to return
return [MyObject objectWithSomeParam:param] ? [MyObject objectWithSomeParam:param] : bar;
```

or running an expensive function...

```
// the expensive function here is run twice
return [self someExpensiveFunction] ? [self someExpensiveFunction] : bar;
```

Both of these would benefit from using

```
return foo ?: bar;
```

Essentially, if the validation object is the same as the return object for true then use the shortened version.

Answer (score 3):

If `obj` is `True`, `obj` is returned.

```
return obj ? : [NSNull null];
```

is equivalent to:

```
id x = obj;
if (x) {
    return x;
else {
    return [NSNull null];
}
```

As long as obj has no side effects it is logically equivalent to:

```
return obj ? obj : [NSNull null]
```

Comment: so it is the same as `return obj ? obj : [NSNull null]`?

Comment: Yes, exactly. I'll add that for reference.

Comment: Yes but it only requires one inspection of the object. Think if it was an expensive function that returned a bool. The method in your comment would run the function twice.

Comment: @DanielHepper no worries. I was going to update your if function to represent the difference but I see that you have done already :)