# C programming Syntax

Tags: c, syntax, syntax-error

Is is possible to have this line of code ?

```
loops_per_msec = (1000000 * loops_per_msec / run_time ? :
        loops_per_msec);
```

My compiler gives me error although this line of code is exactly copied and pasted from other usable source file.

Comment: can u post the error?

Comment: see here for C Operator Precedence:http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/operator_precedence

Comment: What compiler? It uses a gnu extension.

Comment: You are missing a rvalue between the ? and the :. The value to take if the logical expression evaluates to true.

Comment: @RotemVaron Error is Error: expected an expression

Comment: @Kevin I am using MS Visual Studio 2013 to compile .

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The ternary [conditional operator `?:`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%3F:) takes three operands.

But GCC accepts, as an *extension*, to [omit the middle operand](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Conditionals.html#Conditionals).

In your case, coding

```
loops_per_msec = (1000000 * loops_per_msec / run_time ? run_time :
    loops_per_msec);
```

would make any compiler happy.

Comment: can you know let me know how this line of code runs ? >.<

Answer (score 3):

It is possible, it depends which dialect of C language you are using.

```
 ? :
```

Is a GNU extention.

> A GNU extension to C allows omitting the second operand, and using implicitly the first operand as the second also
>   (source wikipedia)

More info on this question: [How wide-spread is this GNU extension on ternary operation?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12420144/how-wide-spread-is-this-gnu-extension-on-ternary-operation)

So you can either fix your code (as other users pointed out), or change compilation option, provided you use a compatible compiler.

Comment: Incidentally, it was proposed for inclusion in C++ at the last ISO meeting, and rejected despite some support.

Comment: Yes, but it is still valid in GNU C++ (clang++, g++).

Answer (score 0):

No your syntax of ?: operator is wrong.

It should be like,

```
result = condition ? if success : (else) fail;
```

You combined `?:` may work in GCC (as [GCC extension](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/C-Extensions.html)), but I will not work in Visual Studio.